# Workflow in SugarCRM is sending too many e-mails?

Tags: sugarcrm

I made work flow in sugar Pro. When a task is done notification email is send to its specific user that a task is done. when a task is 100% complete rather than going 1 mail 16 mails are going to one specific user.

Comment: Try to increase the log level in the administration and check the sugarcrm.log file. In order to help you, we need some more info.

Comment: Hello i made one project and under that project i made 40 tasks . whenever a task is completed email is send to userwho is responsible for the next task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multiple workflows defined that could be causing this trigger? What sort of customizations have been made to the instance?

Comment: Hello i have multiple workflows. Actually i made one project and under that project i made approx 40 task. whenever a task is completed notification is send to the user who is responsible for the next task

Comment: I'm wondering if this is the problem, more than one workflow bumping into one another. Try disabling some workflows until you find the problem go away.

Comment: Hello Sir... thanks for your answers...Can you please give me your personal skype ID so that i can discuss there seriously i want help and i am badly stuck in to this work.